# Is this grammatically correct? "You see a dirt block, above which a stone block"

Tags: grammaticality

Is this grammatically correct?

> You see in front of you a dirt block, above which a stone block.

If not how should it be fixed?

Comment: Hello Claudiu and welcome to the site. Please try to be as specific as possible in the wording of your questions. (What is causing the confusion — the preposition, the pronoun, something else?) General proofreading requests are off-topic here as per the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). Note that you can always improve your questions by clicking the [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/25066/edit) link. Thank you and welcome again.

Comment: I feel "You see a dirt block in front of you" is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

> You see in front of you a dirt block, above it, a stone block.

or

> You see in front of you a dirt block, which has above it a stone block.

Comment: What about "You see in front of you a dirt block; above it, a stone block." that sounds pretty good

Comment: @Claudiu I think it's better to use the semicolon in the first example, yes.  And in the second example, the second comma is extraneous.

Answer (score 6):

Nope. This is better:

> You see in front of you a dirt block,
>   above which is a stone block.

Answer (score 3):

In some literary forms of English, that would be acceptable. In everyday English "which" introduces a relative clause which requires a verb.

So dfan's suggestion is the least change which makes it acceptable in ordinary English; but the "above which" also renders it quite formal, so Mike Vaughan's suggestions are more natural.

Answer (score 0):

I have no argument with the previous answers. I'll add another possibility:

> You see in front of you a dirt block and above it a stone block.

I also wonder whether you mean 'above'. It's correct but it doesn't specify how far above. If it rests directly on the first block then you could indicate that by saying:

> You see in front of you a dirt block and, on top of that, a stone block.